# My HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code run fine on CodePen but locally on my laptop, the CSS doesn't apply?

Tags: html, css

I saved my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code using Notepad, but when locally run in my laptop everything is functioning well except the CSS code: no colour, no bg.

I tried using [CodePen](//codepen.io). the results are shown there properly, but not while using the website locally.

Comment: Provide the file structure and your code to better understand your question. Check out how to make a [minimal reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What debugging have you tried? For example, look in both the codepen and your local implementation using your browser devtools inspect facility and note exactly what difference there is. For example, have you got a doctype? And from where exactly is your stylesheet loaded in the head element etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your CSS in your HTML code using the [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your file path (Example: style.css)">
```

Put this in the `<head>` of your HTML code. :D